# Como fazer para o texto agrupar com imagem

Tags: html, css, css3

**Problema:** Criei um modal para exibir algumas informações e texto sobre a imagem.
Não estou conseguindo fazer o texto ficar na frente da imagem.

**Solução:** Deixar texto na frente da imagem.
Essa imagem é carregada assim que abre a página.

Html/CSS:

```css
.corpoModal {
width: 900px;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

#textoImagem {
padding: 16px;
}
#imagem {
width: 900px;
}

.texto-modal {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
/*cor apenas para exmplo*/
color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
     <!--Modal: Produto em liquidação-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="produtoLiquidacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0 corpoModal">

                    <div class="texto-modal">
                        <h2 id="textoImagem">Texto Aqui</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">

                        <img id="imagem" src="~/assets/img/product/promocoes.jpg" style="width: 900px;"/>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--Footer-->

            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->

        </div>
    </div>
```

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: precisa usar `position: absolute` para isso no elemento que tem o texto, e depois `margin`  para ajustar exatamente onde quer que o texto apareça. Ou pode colocar o texto dentro da mesma `div` que contém a imagem e usar só a propriedade `margin` para posicionar

Comment: Mas o texto já está na frente da imagem... http://prntscr.com/oljq7t não entendi

Comment: Leia, esse tutorial sobre a propriedade position do CSS no https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, vai te ajudar a posicionar o texto sobre a imagem ou outro conteúdo.

Comment: Olá Hugo, então esse mesmo código no meu projeto estava aparecendo atrás da imagem não sei o porquê. Rs Mais consegui resolver  obrigado pela atenção